# New line in a Paragraph not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paragraph

First let me starte that I've been psending the last 2 hours searching the web and trying solutions, nothing worked. I've been trying to make a new line in a Paragraph, but do'sent work.
I'm using Jquery mobile and editing a paragraph with $('.selector').text(); from a javascript.

I got the follow code:

```
function popupBasicPris() {
    $('#prisMatchPopup').text("Du har indtastet: <br />"+ 
    "Pris: " + document.getElementById("textinputpris").value.toString() +
    "<br /> Vil du sende?");
    }
```

The code is run from a button click.
My problem is that it just writes 
 instead of making a new line in the shown text.

Comment: And what do you think why the method is called `text` …? http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `.text` to `.html`, as you are including html elements within your output.

Reference [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Yep worked thanks, if i may ask when should i use .text instead of html?

Comment: You'd use `.html()` when you're including HTML elements in the output (or reading in content which contains HTML elements). You'd use `.text()` when you just want the textual content, with no HTML elements included.

Answer (score 0):

```
function popupBasicPris() {
  $("#prisMatchPopup").html(
    "Du har indtastet: <br /> Pris: " + $("#textinputpris").val() + "<br /> Vil du sende?"
  );
}
```